# (SPARK) What is the best way to partition data on which multiple filters are applied?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, filtering, data-partitioning, azure-databricks

I am working in Spark (on azure databricks) with a 15 billion rows file that looks like this :

```
+---------+---------------+----------------+-------------+--------+------+
|client_id|transaction_key|transaction_date|   product_id|store_id|spend|
+---------+---------------+----------------+-------------+--------+------+
|        1|  7587_20121224|      2012-12-24|     38081275|     787| 4.54|
|        1| 10153_20121224|      2012-12-24|         4011|    1053| 2.97|
|        2|  6823_20121224|      2012-12-24|    561122924|     683| 2.94|
|        3| 11131_20121224|      2012-12-24|     80026282|    1131|  0.4|
|        3|  7587_20121224|      2012-12-24|        92532|     787| 5.49|
```

This data is used for all my queries, which consist mostly in groupby (product_id for example), sum and count distinct :

```
results = trx.filter(col("transaction_date") > "2018-01-01"
                     & 
                     col("product_id").isin(["38081275", "4011"])
             .groupby("product_id")
             .agg(sum("spend").alias("total_spend"),
                  countdistinct("transaction_key").alias("number_trx"))
```

I never need to use 100% of this data, I always start with a filter on :

- *transaction_date* (1 000 distinct values)
- *product_id* (1 000 000 distinct values)
- *store_id* (1 000 distinct values)

==> What is the best way to partition this data in a parquet file ?

I initially partitionned the data on *transaction_date* :

```
trx.write.format("parquet").mode("overwrite").partitionBy("transaction_date").save("dbfs:/linkToParquetFile")
```

This will create partitions that are approximately the same size.
However, most of the queries will require to keep at least 60% of the *transaction_date*, whereas only a few *product_id* are usually selected in 1 query.
(70% of the *store_id* kept usually)

==> Is there a way to build a parquet file taking this into account ?

It seems partitionning the data on *product_id* would create way too much partitions...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

for example you can use multiple columns for partitioning (it creates sub folders) and spark can use partition filters

another good idea is bucketing more information [here](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-bucketing.html) (to avoid extra shuffle)

Example with hive

```
trx.write.partitionBy("transaction_date", "store_id").bucketBy(1000, "product_id").saveAsTable("tableName")
```

to read it use

```
spark.table("tableName")
```

Comment: Thanks @Kamrus, that did the trick !
For some reason I thought that partitionning by several columns would create folders based on a combination of these columns.
It however creates sub folders into each folders, which allows me to use partition filters very efficiently.